# What is the replacement for InnerHitsBuilder?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

On Elasticsearch 2, we are using `InnerHitsBuilder` to fetch additional information:

```
        SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest();
        SearchSourceBuilder source = SearchSourceBuilder
            .searchSource()
            .fetchSource(new String[] { "md5" }, null)
            .query(query);

        if (deduplicateRequest.getByOwner()) {
            InnerHitsBuilder innerHitsBuilder = source.innerHitsBuilder();
            InnerHitsBuilder.InnerHit innerHit = new InnerHitsBuilder.InnerHit()
                .setType("item-annotation")
                .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("annotation-type", "item-owner"));
            innerHitsBuilder.addInnerHit("owner", innerHit);
        }
```

In Elasticsearch 5, the class has disappeared. It was not properly deprecated and is not documented in the "breaking changes" section of the changelog (or least, I couldn't find it after manually opening all the individual web pages making up the breaking changes section, one by one, searching on each of them, one by one.)

Javadoc on Elasticsearch is awfully sparse as well.

Elasticsearch also wasn't calling the `innerHitsBuilder()` method anywhere in its own code, so I can't find any examples of the usage change.

In any case, the class is now gone and I'm supposed to be updating the code to the replacement. What is the replacement?